# WinForms ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged not firing when typing few chars followed by Alt+Down

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

**In short**

When I type a character in a ComboBox, press Alt+Down followed by Enter or Tab, the SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't fire, even though the SelectedIndex value *does* change!  Why doesn't the event fire?

**Update**
The same error occurs if you type a character, press Alt+Down and then type Esc. You would expect the Esc to cancel the change. However, the SelectedIndex *does* change, and the SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't fire.

What should happen if you just type Alt+Down, use the arrow keys to browse to an entry, and *then* type Esc? Should the selected index be set back to its original value?

---

**Not so short**

I have a WinForm application with a ComboBox on it. The ComboBox' SelectedIndexChanged event is wired up to a event handler that shows the SelectedItem in a Label control. The ComboBox' Items collection has three values: "One", "Two", and "Three".

- When I select an item with the mouse, the event fires.
- When I scroll the mouse, the event fires.
- When I use Alt+Down to expand the combobox and walk through the items with Up and Down, the event fires.
- But... When I type in the first character of a value, *then* press Alt+Down, followed by Enter or Tab, the value does get selected and is shown in the combobox, but the event doesn't fire.

I've also added a button that shows the SelectedIndex. It shows the SelectedIndex *has* changed. So even though the SelectedIndex does change, the SelectedIndexChanged event does not fire!

*If I just type in a valid value like* `One` *the event doesn't fire either, but in that case a click on the button reveals the SelectedIndex indeed hasn't changed. So in that case the behavior is normal.*

---

To reproduce, create a Form and add a ComboBox, a Label and a Button. Place the following code in the Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "One",
                "Two",
                "Three"
            });
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Selected index: " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected item: " + comboBox1.SelectedItem +
                "\nSelected index: " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd the same issue and so I handled TextChanged event. As per MSDN page - SelectedIndexChanged event will be fires when the **value** of the SelectedIndex property changes.

Comment: @adatapost: The way I describe things here (type the first char, then Alt+Down) then click on the button) shows that the SelectedIndex actually *does* change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate DropDown property value here is DropDownList.  It doesn't have this problem.

Coming up with a workaround for your specific problem with the DropDown style set to DropDown is quite difficult.  It allows the user type arbitrary text and even a perfect match with one of the dropdown items doesn't change the SelectedIndex.  You'd have to implement the Validating event and look for a match yourself.  The DropDownClosed event would be good for your specific scenario.  But really, always use DropDownList if you want perfect matches.

Comment: My situation is not that the user types in the complete entry, just the first character, then Alt+Down. And as my Button shows, this way it *does* change the SelectedIndex. That's exactly what boggles me. The SelectedIndex *does* change, but the event doesn't fire.

Comment: Yup, sad isn't it?  My point was that you can never rely on SelectedIndex unless you set the DropDown style to DropDownList.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have. But by using that DropDownStyle it's not really a combobox anymore. It disables the possibility to type in a value that's not in the list. It also makes it unable to type multiple characters of the value you want to select. If you type AB to get to an entry starting with AB, you actually move to the first entry starting with B.

Comment: Meh, this *never* confuzzles a user.

Comment: For a user who mostly uses the keyboard (like myself) it is very annoying if in a combobox, you can not type the first two, or maybe three characters in order to jump to the item you want. It's a pain if you can only type in the first letter and than have to scroll down the items to find the one you want.

Comment: I'd have to recommend you implement your own ComboBox control so you can make it work just the way you want it.  The drop-down list is a bit tricky btw, it is a toplevel window.  Do get a regular user to use your version at the early point in time, programmers and users do tend to have very different needs.  A common user desire is 'make it work like it does in any other program I use'.  They are a bit stuck-in-the-mud that way.

Comment: I've marked your answer as the answer, even though it doesn't solve my problem. I suppose you are right about users being a bit stuck-in-the-mud.

Comment: I believe the problem is connected with losing the focus.  
The event will only be fired when the UI widget gets refocused again.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried several google searches in order to find a definitive answer on this but didn't find one before. Just now I found a thread that actually refers to a Microsoft knowledge base article about the problem. Article [KB948869](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948869) describes the problem.

The knowledge base article suggest to create your own combobox and override the ProcessDialogKey method.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
            this.DroppedDown = false;
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

I've tried it, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Which is a bit strange. I would expect a workaround described in a knowledge base article to be accurate.

I found another workaround though, which is to use the DropDownClosed event in stead.

```
private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "DroDownClosed Selected index: " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

This *does* seem to work, but only when using DropDownStyle.DropDown. When you set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList, typing a character does not fire the DropDownClosed (as there is no actual drop down in that case). Only if you actually open up the drop down list and select a value the DropDownClosed event is fired.

So, both options are not really a good answer.

**Update**
I've even tried overriding property SelectedIndex in MyComboBox, having it call `OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty)`. After typing a character and pressing Alt+Down, the setter is executed, but it's setting the value to -1, which it already is. After pressing Tab, the setter isn't executed again, although somehow the SelectedIndex value *does* change. It looks like the ComboBox is directly changing the backing field for SelectedIndex, bypassing the setting. I believe something like this probably also happens in the real ComboBox.

Answer (score 3):

I had the <kbd>ESC</kbd> problem on a DropDownList-style combobox. I slightly modified what worked for me to accommodate your needs:

```
public class MyComboBox : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
  private bool _sendSic;

  protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    if (DroppedDown)
    {
      switch(e.KeyCode)
      {
        case System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Escape:
          _sendSic = true;
          break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Tab:
        case System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter:
          if(DropDownStyle == System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown)
            _sendSic = true;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  protected override void OnDropDownClosed(System.EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnDropDownClosed(e);

    if(_sendSic)
    {
      _sendSic = false;
      OnSelectedIndexChanged(System.EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is listening to keystrokes that come in while the dropdown is open. If it's <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for a `DropDown`-style ComboBox or <kbd>ESC</kbd> for a `DropDownList`-style ComboBox, a `SelectedIndexChanged`-Event is triggered when the DropDown is closed.
I have never ever used `ComboBoxStyle.Simple` and don't really know how it does or should work, but since it to the best of my knowledge never displays a DropDown, this should be safe even for that style.

If you don't want to derive from `ComboBox` to build your own control, you can also apply similar logic to a ComboBox on a form by subscribing to it's `PreviewKeyDown` and `DropDownClosed` events.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Here is code I've used.

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "One",
                "Two",
                "Three"
});

comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged+=(sa,ea)=>
 {
   label1.Text = "Selected index: " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
 };
comboBox1.TextChanged+= (sa, ea) =>
 {
 comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);

 //OR
 //comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.Text);
  comboBox1.SelectionStart  = comboBox1.Text.Length;
};
```

Comment: If I type in a complete existing entry, this does indeed trigger the SelectedIndexChanged and show the index on the label. But if I type in one character (e.g. T) then pres Alt+Down, then Tab, the entry in the combobox changes to Two, the TextChanged event fires, your code sets SelectedIndex to 1, but SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire. This is because pressing Tab already changes the SelectedIndex to 1 before the TextChanged event fires. Setting SelectedIndex from within TextChanged then doesn't actually change the index, so the SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire.

Comment: Something else is wrong too. After typing `Two` the match is made by TextChanged, leading to a change in SelectedIndex, which leads to firing SelectedIndexChanged, which sets the label to show the index. But... when I leave the combobox, the actual SelectedIndex is set to -1! This doesn't trigger SelectedIndexChanged, but if you inspected the value in the debugger, you'll see it is set to -1.

Comment: Agree! You can try autocomplete feature and it will work. According to social MSDN page - SelectedIndexChanged Event : "Occurs when the SelectedIndex property has changed." it's not a bug -- it's a feature. Thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/59a23260-bf7b-455e-bbf2-2ad9c4aa07e0

Comment: Setting AutoComplete to AppendSuggest and AutoCompleteSource to ListItems does make things a lot better, although the SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire until you leave the control. However, my original problem still exists. When you type a character, then Alt+Down, then Tab, the SelectedIndex still doesn't change. Also, using Del to clear the control doesn't fire the event.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up deriving my own class from ComboBox:

```
public class EditableComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected int backupIndex;
    protected string backupText;

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        backupIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
        if (backupIndex == -1) backupText = this.Text;
        else backupText = null;
        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
    {
        backupIndex = -2;
        base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        backupIndex = -2;
        base.OnSelectionIndexChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backupIndex > -2 && this.SelectedIndex != backupIndex)
        {
            if (backupIndex > -1)
            {
                this.SelectedIndex = backupIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                string oldText = backupText;
                this.SelectedIndex = -1;
                this.Text = oldText;
                this.SelectAll();
            }
        }
        base.OnDropDownClosed(e);
    }
}
```