# ComboBox get selected value independently of selection method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

**Goal** : **Get selected value from ComboBox no matter if the user selected the value by clicking, pressing the enter key, pressing tab to autocomplete etc....**

I have a `dictionary<string, string[]>` with key: ID and Value(s): version(s)

I have 2 ComboBoxes say CB1(containing keys\ID's) and CB2 as such :

[image]

When the user selects an ID(key) in CB1 the corresponding value(s) is filled CB2.

To do this I made use of the `CB1_SelectionChangeCommited`, `CB1_Leave`, `CB1_KeyPressed` methods. The later doesn't work properly as it doesn't detect key presses whatsoever. It's code is as follows

```
private void ComboBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            if (comboBox3.Items.Contains($"{comboBox3.Text}"))
            {
                comboBox4.Items.Clear();
                comboBox4.Text = string.Empty;


                foreach (string version in dependenciesData.dependencyDic[Convert.ToString(comboBox3.Text)])
                {
                    comboBox4.Items.Add(version);
                }
                comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question :**

**- How can I fix the `CB_Keypress` method**

**OR**

**- Is there another way around to do what I want?**

Comment: Do not post code as image. Please, include it as text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works pretty well for me if I set the `AutocompleteMode` to `Append` or `SuggestAppend` and the `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems`:

```cs
private void ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dependenciesData.dependencyDic
           .TryGetValue((string)comboBox3.SelectedItem, out string[] values)) {

        comboBox4.DataSource = values;
        comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Setting the `AutocompleteMode` to `Suggest` does not work.

If it is ensured that the dictionary contains all combo box entries as key. Then this can be simplyfied a litte bit:

```cs
if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex >= 0) {
    comboBox4.DataSource =
        dependenciesData.dependencyDic[(string)comboBox3.SelectedItem];
    comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I set the data source of `comboBox3` like this:

```cs
comboBox3.DataSource =dependenciesData.dependencyDic.Keys
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

---

The easiest way to allow the user entering only allowed values is to set the `DropDownStyle` of combo box to `DropDownList`. With this setting, he cannot edit the combo box text anymore, however he still gets autocomplete suggestions.

---

A few notes to your coding style:

- Nested if-statements `if (condition1) { if (condition2) { ... } }` can be written as `if (condition1 && condition2) { ... }`.
- Instead of adding individual items to a combo box with `Items.Add(...)`, you can set the [ComboBox.DataSource Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759579/winforms-combobox-selectedindexchanged-not-firing-when-typing-few-chars-followed) to a list or array.
- If the combo box contains strings, you can simply cast the `SelectedItem` property to `string` instead converting it to `string`. (There is no conversion to be done since it is already a `string` that is statically typed as `object`).
- You are testing whether the combo box items contain a text which is a `O(n)` operation. You can do this more efficiently by performing the test on the dictionary containing the same texts as keys, which is a [O(1) operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0#remarks).
- You use the redundant string interpolation `$"{comboBox3.Text}"`. Simply using `comboBox3.Text` yields the same result.

Comment: Wow ! thank you for your solution and your remarks on my code. Very much appreciated